# Как неявно передать аргумент во все функции с помощью Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

Видел такую штуку, что в теле функции можно написать что-то вроде:

```
myArg provided by "hello world"
```

То есть такой код будет работать:

```
fun foo1() { 
    myArg provided ...
    foo2()
}

fun foo2() {
    println(myArg)
}
```

И тогда аргумент myArg будет по умолчанию вставляться во все вызовы функций. Но забыл точный синтаксис и как это называется. Пожалуйста, помогите вспомнить

Comment: это вроде бы называется как "получатели для лямбд с контекстом", что означает, что в лямбда-функции можно использовать объект на котором она вызывается, как внутренний контекст

Comment: Не, это не also/run/with
Там по умолчанию всегда слово this
И синтаксис другой

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, укажите метки Android и Jetpack Compose, наверное речь про [Composition Local](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal).

Comment: Господи, да, это то что я искал!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во фреймворке Jetpack Compose есть [`CompositionLocal`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal). Например, когда вы задаете тему вашему проекту, она применяется для всех функций, которые есть внутри, без явной передачи аргументов:

```kotlin
MaterialTheme(colorScheme = darkColorScheme()) {
    MyContent()
}
```

```
@Composable
fun MyContent() {
    Text("Lalala", color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary)
}
```

Подобную штуку можно реализовать с помощью функций `CompositionLocalProvider()` и `compositionLocalOf()`, которые есть в Jetpack Compose. В официальном гайде [есть хороший пример](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal#creating-apis), как создать свой `CompositionLocal`.

Например, воссоздадим свою тему, в которой будет только один цвет:

```kotlin
class MyTheme(val textColor: Color = Color.Black)
```

Для этого создадим объект `CompositionLocal` с помощью метода `compositionLocalOf()`. Такую константу принято называть с префикса `Local`:

```kotlin
val LocalTheme = compositionLocalOf { MyTheme() }
```

Все готово, теперь можем задать тему с помощью функции `CompositionLocalProvider`:

```kotlin
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalTheme provides MyTheme(Color.Red)) {
    MyContent()
}
```

А получить текущие значения из темы можно с помощью вызова `LocalTheme.current`:

```
@Composable
fun MyContent() {
    Text("Lalala", color = LocalTheme.current.textColor)
}
```